# Angular 4 - I need help debugging ZoneAwareError

Tags: angular

Do I need help debugging this error to find out what is wrong?
I using Angular4 and usually occurs when I have a problem in the html, but does not indicate which, or at least I do not know how to see it, and I lose a lot of time every time I find one.
Greetings.

```
"Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
Error
at Error.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3752:33)
at ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3749:35)
at injectionError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:1442:86)
at noProviderError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:1480:12)
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2981:19)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:3020:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2952:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2821:21)
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:3768:52)
at AdminModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:3768:52)
at resolveDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11135:45)
at createClass (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:10993:35)
at createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:10832:37)
at createViewNodes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:12182:49)
at createRootView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:12087:5)
at ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3752:33)
at resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3425:31)
at resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3396:17)
at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3473:17
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3127:31)
at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:4327:37)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3126:36)
at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2926:47)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3306:35)
at HTMLButtonElement.ZoneTask.invoke 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3184:25)"
```

Comment: Do you have any `throw "Error";` statements in your code?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate. Did you look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108195/angular4-zoneawareerror

Comment: If the link above doesn't help, please provide more details or preferably create a plunker to better assist you with your error.

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand!
in:

```
    "Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
Error
at Error.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3752:33)
at ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3749:35)
at injectionError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:1442:86)
at noProviderError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:1480:12)
```

I inject a service  in component (**injectionError**) and I do not declare it as provider in module (**noProviderError**).